# How to remove repition of documents in mongodb using pycharm

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pycharm

I just coded a database for my project and when I open the database in MongoDB Compass it repeats the data every time the compass is loaded. I am just confused why the output i.e. the name of the students is repeated again after the total collection ends.

```
import pymongo
connection = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
database = connection['FaceRecognition']
collection = database['Data']
data = ([{
"Name": "Arun Regmi",``
"StudentNo": "1",
"Attended Days": "",
 },
{
 "Name": "Abhinav Arya",
 "StudentNo": "2",
 "Attended Days": ""
 },
{
 "Name": "Asim Mahat",
 "StudentNo": "3",
 "Attended Days": ""
 },
{
 "Name": "Bhabuk Kunwar",
 "StudentNo": "4",
 "Attended Days": ""
 },
{
 "Name": "Unique Karki",
 "StudentNo": "5",
 "Attended Days": ""
 }])
 collection.insert_many(data)
```

[image: Compass showing repetition of data]

Comment: This is both far too unclear and vague, and possibly off-topic for Stack Overflow. In addition, please include all information as text in the post itself, not in images.

Comment: I am new to post the problem here . Now I corrected the program. Could you help me out ?

Comment: I corrected my program now the error was that I place " before the number.

Comment: A quote? Where?

Comment: at the student no it should have been  "StudentNo": 4,

Comment: Oh well that’s not a single one-off issue, that has to do with the type of the values. What did you do to fix it? Can you post the fix?